# Is that possible to Accommodate Spinner inside Scroll View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to accommodate 4 spinners inside a Scroll View. But i won't be able to do that. 
Is there any way is there to accommodate spinner inside Scroll View??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:
A `ScrollView` can only host one direct child, so if you put the spinners inside a `LinearLayout` every thing will be fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible to place the spinners inside horizontal scroll view and have them next to each other?

Comment: Yea sure why not.